# Jgrasp Tic Tac Toe Searching A Two Dimensional array

Tags: arrays, search, jgrasp

Today I am creating a Tic-Tac-Toe program using a two dimensional array in Java. I have written most of the code and have my value for the "X" and "O" to be set inside the array. What I cannot seem to figure out is how to search the array to test if there is a winner. My current method was:

```
if(board[0][0] && board[0][1] && board[0][2] == x)
   { 
      //Some player wins
   }
```

Of course this doesn't bring me the results I had hoped. I would love an explanation on how I can check my array and call a winning method. I kindly ask that it not be completed for me, while this is absolutely much too kind it would also not allow me to further my knowledge. Thank you very much and I hope to hear back from someone soon!

Program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class TicTacToe
{
private String[][]board;
private static final int ROWS = 3;
private static final int COLUMNS = 3;

public TicTacToe()
{
  board = new String[ROWS][COLUMNS];
  for(int r=0; r<ROWS; r++)
     for(int c = 0; c<COLUMNS; c++)
        board[r][c] = " "; //fill array with spaces
}

public void set(int r, int c, String player)
{
  if (board[r][c].equals(" "))
     board[r][c] = player; //place the "x" or "o"
}

/* toString() creates a String representation of board, for example,
|x o|
| x |
| o|
*/
public String toString()
{
  String d = ""; //d is the display
  for(int r=0; r<ROWS; r++)
  {
     d = d + "|";
     for(int c = 0; c<COLUMNS; c++)
        d = d+board[r][c];
     d = d + "|\n";
  }
  return d;
}
/*PseudoCode for winner:
If three of same type match in diagonal, row, column, then return a winner      based on what varibale
EX: [0][0] [0][1] [0][2] all are X, therefore player with X wins
*/
public boolean winner(String player)
{
//Return Winner
}



public class TicTacToeDriver
{
  public void main(String [] args)
  {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     String player = "x"; //first player
     TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
     boolean done = false;
     System.out.println(game); 
     while (!done)
     {
        System.out.print("Row for " + player + " (-1 TO EXIT): ");
        int row = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (row<0) //user wants to end the game
           done = true;
        else
        {
           System.out.print("Column for " + player + ": " );
           int col = keyboard.nextInt();

           game.set(row, col, player);//update board
           done = game.winner(player); //check for winner
           if(done)
              System.out.println("Player " + player + " is the winner");

           if(player.equals("x")) //change player
              player = "o";
           else
              player = "x";
        }
        System.out.println(game); //game over
     }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a table, or some kind of raster.

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaGame_TicTacToe.html

```
  public static boolean hasWon(int theSeed, int currentRow, int currentCol) {
  return (board[currentRow][0] == theSeed         // 3-in-the-row
               && board[currentRow][1] == theSeed
               && board[currentRow][2] == theSeed
          || board[0][currentCol] == theSeed      // 3-in-the-column
               && board[1][currentCol] == theSeed
               && board[2][currentCol] == theSeed
          || currentRow == currentCol            // 3-in-the-diagonal
               && board[0][0] == theSeed
               && board[1][1] == theSeed
               && board[2][2] == theSeed
          || currentRow + currentCol == 2  // 3-in-the-opposite-diagonal
               && board[0][2] == theSeed
               && board[1][1] == theSeed
               && board[2][0] == theSeed);
```

}